# Parse of XMl with dojo(Ajax) error in IE because of encoding

Tags: ajax, encoding, websphere, dojo

I want to parse XML with dojo(Ajax) in IE and other browser run perfectly.

Example JavaScript Dojo :

```
ar xhrArgs = {
url: link,
sync:true,
preventCache:true,
load: function(responseresponse,ioArgs){
var dom = dojox.xml.parser.parse(responseresponse);
var docNode = dom.documentElement;
}
error: function(error){

alert("An unexpected error occurred: " + error); 
//IN IE go to here if the XML have characters like this áéí an others

}
```

Example XML :

```
<?xml version=\1.0\ encoding=\ISO-8859-1\ ?>
 <xml>
    <accountNumber>áéíóú</accountNumber>
 </xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have accented characters in your xml document, make sure that you use an encoding type that supports them.  Hint:  utf-8 doesn't!  Try ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) or encode your xml data as utf-8.